# Ruby: is there a way to access (and alter) member variables directly?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby (and OOP best practices) and I'm currently working through some exercises involving classes.  One of them has me making a dictionary that maps "keywords" to their "definitions".  Below is a simplified version:

```
class Dictionary
  attr_accessor :entries, :keywords

  def initialize(opts = {})
    @entries = opts
    @keywords = opts.keys.sort
  end
end
```

Anyhow, I have a question about altering the value of member variables within a class implementation. Below I have an example of an instance method where I need to update the values of @entries and @keywords.

```
def add(entry)
    if entry.instance_of?(Hash)
      @entries = @entries.merge!(entry)
    else
      @entries = entries.merge!({entry => nil})
    end
    @keywords = @entries.keys.sort
  end
```

In the above example, I use the public setter method by invoking the '=' operator.
This has some slight performance drawbacks as I am creating a new Hash when that r-value is evaluated.

I know that it's typically best to use setters when accessing instances of variables, but I'm wondering if it's possible (even if not advised) to alter member variables of a class without using setters?  For example, in a language like python you can call a member function on a member variable that alters its value if you don't use getters/setters. In ruby, however, it seems that getters and setters are required for access (unless I'm mistaken).  I was thinking that perhaps there is a way to implement a getter as returning a reference to the member variable so it behaves like direct access?  The way I am imagining this, the result would look something like this form an intuitive point of view:

```
 def add(entry)
    if entry.instance_of?(Hash)
      @entries.merge!(entry)
    else
      @entries.merge!({entry => nil})
    end
    @keywords.push(entry.keys.first).sort!
  end
```

(In the above example, in practice none of the member variables @entries, @keywords are actually updated after a call to add is made, but you get the idea of what its' supposed to do.)  If the above example did work as intended, it would seem to be a bit more efficient than the first implementation.

Is there any way in Ruby to do something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: Your `@keywords` update logic (last line) is flawed. If `entry` is a hash, it could contain multiple `keyword => definition` pairs. Adding only `entry.keys.first` to `@keywords` would miss the other keywords. Likewise, if a keyword already exists, you would add it twice to `@keywords`.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks.  Looking back, it's probably best to make keywords a getter that just returns the keys in entries rather than its own instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use the public setter method by invoking the '=' operator

No, you don't. No setter invocation there.

> If the above example did work as intended, it would seem to be a bit more efficient than the first implementation.

False. This example is doing **exactly** the same thing (save for the ivar assignment, which is a single instruction), Therefore, performance will be identical. Always measure performance, don't assume or guess.

---

```
  def add(entry)
    if entry.instance_of?(Hash)
      @entries.merge!(entry)
    else
      @entries.merge!({entry => nil})
    end
    @keywords.push(entry.keys.first).sort!
  end
```

> In the above example, in practice none of the member variables @entries, @keywords are actually updated after a call to add is made

They should update. Must be an error in the calling code. BTW, you should write it like this:

```
  def add(entry)
    if entry.instance_of?(Hash)
      entries.merge!(entry)
    else
      entries.merge!({entry => nil})
    end
    keywords.push(entry.keys.first).sort!
  end
```

You have defined the getter methods. It's a shame that they're sitting unused.

Comment: Ah, it seems I was mistaken.  The second implementation does work after all.  Thanks for the clarification!

In regards to the setter, is it only invoked outside of the class definition (i.e. on instances of the class)?

Comment: @LukeEspina: no, it can be invoked from inside the class too. But in your case, you were setting ivars directly, without using the setters. The setter usage would be: `self.entries = ...`

Comment: @LukeEspina: btw, don't forget to accept (and maybe upvote) helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'm brand new here.  You've been very helpful.  I didn't realize there was a difference between using @var and self.var until your comment.